# How does one get the method name from a WCF Request in Application_BeginRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I'm hosting WCF in an IIS, in my HttpApplication I'd like to get the WCF operation contract name (method being called) in the `Application_BeginRequest` method:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var request = Context.Request;
}
```

I get the request from the context but I'm unable to understand how to find the name of the WCF method that was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the incoming HTTP Headers:

`Console.WriteLine(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["SOAPAction"]);`

This will spit out the full value, in my sample that was:

> "http://tempuri.org/IService1/DoWork"

It is probably worth noting, but [`OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageheaders.action(v=vs.110).aspx) won't work in `Application_BeginRequest` because the operation hasn't started yet, so `OperationContext.Current` is null.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a SOAP WCF service, you can check the service reference in the project and look at the references. If it is a SOAP WCF and you have not add it as a service reference, right click on the project and go to add service reference. Then add the url and the namespace you wish to use. You can also navigate to the WISDL to see the methods there. To do that, you can just pull up the url in the browser in this format http://{WebServiceUrl}/{NameOfService}.svc?wsdl

If this is a REST WCF service, then there may be an API reference provided with the service. For example, that url could be something like this http://{WebServiceUrl}/{NameOfService}/API/help